# Saving the output of calculation as the new input of a calculator

Tags: php, calculator

I want to make a calculator in PHP. I need a way to save the result of calculation as a new predefined input.

Example: user multiplies 5 and 6 and gets a result of 30. If they want to multiply the result they presently need to input 30 again and choose a desired operation.

I want to save the result of every operation so that the user can continue to do calculations with the result. If the user doesn't want to further use the result they just need to enter a new number and click submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kalkulator</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["posalji_vrijednosti"]))
{
    $b_1 = $_POST["broj_1"];
    $op = $_POST["operacija"];
    $b_2 = $_POST["broj_2"];;
}
// Varijabla koja ce sadrzavati rezultat
$rezultat = "";
// Program odradjuje svoje ispod
if ($op == "*")
{
    $rezultat = $b_1 * $b_2;
}
elseif ($op == "/")
{
    $rezultat = $b_1 / $b_2;
}
elseif ($op == "+")
{
    $rezultat = $b_1 + $b_2;
}
elseif ($op == "-")
{
    $rezultat = $b_1 - $b_2;
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Unesi prvi broj</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="broj_1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Odaberi operaciju</td>
            <td><select name="operacija">
                    <option value="+">+</option>
                    <option value="-">-</option>
                    <option value="*">*</option>
                    <option value="/">/</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unesi drugi broj</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="broj_2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="posalji_vrijednosti" value="              =              "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <td>
                <?php
                echo "Rezultat: $rezultat";
                ?>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can: 1.put the result in the main input field as/per default, 2. serve a button that the user can click to put the (shown) result into the input -> needs javascript, but is an easy task. (there are for sure 3rd, 4th, ... options. These are just the obvious ones)

Comment: in option one you can pre-select the values in the input (via javascript), so that when the user starts typing he will overwrite the default.

Comment: Another obvious option is to create a variable and assign every result in there and make it the default input everytime. If/Else might be needed or it depends upon your logic.

Comment: Thank you for recomendations. I would like to do it using just PHP.

Comment: If that's your choice then go. But I would strongly recommend to consider using JS.

Comment: @Irvin I tried to do just that, save the result in a variable, but I don't know ho to put that result_variable at the beginning of program, before user chooses to type a new input.

Comment: At this point in comments, you should post your code.

Comment: You could use sessions and conditional statements on if something is set/not empty in the inputs; best I can offer given lack of code. The question IMHO is unclear/too broad. *"so please go easy on that "down-vote" button"* - Questions as such and without code, tend to attract downvotes and votes to close, this being a Stack pro tip.

Comment: I just added my code, that is just beginning of a program I am trying to write.
@Fred-ii- thanx for the tip

Comment: `<input type="text" name="broj_1" value="<?php echo $rezultat; ?>">`

Comment: @Jeff how come I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: @NedzadGanic see how fast Jeff came up with a solution after you posted your code? ;-) and you're welcome.

Comment: Nedzad, if what @Jeff posted in comments solved the question, I believe that warrants as an answer in order to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If you think it's appropriate, I'll post that as an "answer". ...but also add some more options into that answer

Comment: @Jeff I feel it does. The question shouldn't be left "unanswered", IMHO.

Comment: is there any other way of doing what I was trying to do, except what @Jeff posted, with using just PHP?

Comment: @NedzadGanic that is *just* PHP

Comment: I mean, some other way of doing it?

Comment: I'm writing you an answer with a bit of js included...

Comment: @NedzadGanic Yes, there are always many ways to do something. But it always depends on what is important to you, what we dont know.

Comment: thank you all, I got the answer to my question

Comment: @NedzadGanic consider accepting Jeff's answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve the use with the calculated result as the new input, you just need to put the result as the new `value` of your input.

The simplest solution & answer is:

```
 <input type="text" name="broj_1" value="<?php echo $rezultat; ?>">
```

If you want the user to be able to initially start from scratch you can still show it, but pre-select the result:

```
<?php
    $rezultat = ""; // init that var

    // your calculation
    $rezultat = "30";
?>
<input type="text" id="inputField" value="<?php echo $rezultat; ?>">
<script>
    input = document.getElementById('inputField');
    input.select();
</script>
```

Or you can not show the result in input, but serve a button that will insert the result into that input:

```
<?php
    $rezultat = ""; // init that var
    // your calculation
    $rezultat = "30";
?>
<input type="hidden" id="result" value="<?php echo $rezultat; ?>">
<button onClick="copyValue()">re-use Result</button><br>
<input type="text" id="inputField">
<script>
function copyValue() {
    result = document.getElementById('result');
    input = document.getElementById('inputField');
    input.value = result.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome Jeff. Btw, (off-topic lol), I notice you're a musician; same here. I play mostly all stringed instruments myself and many more ;-) cheers ♫

Comment: I'm more on the keys. Guitar & Bass only when drunk... Cheers!

Comment: *Haha!* I get ya. I play a bit of those myself; if it plays a sound, you can be sure I'll have a go at it. All the best in the New Year Jeff, *cheers*